# Exception javax.persistence.Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()Ljavax/persistence/PersistenceUtil

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a application which uses Spring MVC, IOC, Hibernate Validator, Hibernate (Annotation Based) with jdk1.6.

I have pom.xml with below entries

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am doing Hibernate Validation something like this

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class DepartmentForm {

    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter department name")
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String department;

    @Size(max = 60)
    private String description;
}
```

But application is giving error as below

```
exception 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()Ljavax/persistence/PersistenceUtil;
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()Ljavax/persistence/PersistenceUtil;
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:33)
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:112)
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:764)
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:331)
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:278)
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:260)
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:213)
    org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
    org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:86)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:692)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:807)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:359)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented, [PersistenceUtil](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceUtil.html) was introduced in JPA **2.0**. Current JPA API dependency is to the version 1.0. Problem is solved by obtaining JPA API (2.0) via following instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have tried by adding 2.0 jpa dependancy, but did not worked out

Comment: Then you still have in runtime classpath javax.persistence.Persistence which comes from somewhere else. Can be from transitive maven dependency or from container.